# convert json to java POJO using stream api

Tags: gson

I have a json file and using below code to convert json into java POJO

```
    reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream, "UTF-8"));
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        Example st = gson.fromJson(reader, Example.class);
    }
```

my json structure is as:

```
{
  "$id": "students.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "project": {
      "$id": "project",
      "projectList": [
        "ABC"
      ]
    },
    "students": {
      "$id": "/properties/students",
      "type": "array",
      "subelements": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "$id": "/properties/students/subelements/properties/id",
            "examples": [
              "Y"
            ]
          },
          "dep": {
            "$id": "/properties/students/subelements/properties/dep",
            "examples": [
              "X"
            ]
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "id",
          "dep"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "project"
  ]
}
```

And I only need students.subelements.id.examples[0] and students.subelements.dep.examples[0] from list of students 
currently my java object classes are:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "project",
    "elements"
})
public class Example {

    /**
     * The project
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("project")
    @JsonPropertyDescription("The project code")
    private String project;
    @JsonProperty("elements")
    private List<Student> elements = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}

    //student class
    public class Student{
    private String id;
    private String dep;
    }
```

and I am facing below exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NAME at line 2 column 4 path $.
```

so please help me what will be my exact java object class according to provided json and I will get only required fields from that class ?

Comment: you have trailing commas in your json

Comment: These are part of data

Comment: students.subelements.dep.examples array is followed by a comma - this is not valid because it's the last field of dep

Comment: Issue is still same without comma too. I have edited in question too

Comment: there are more trailing comma's - use json lint tool. projectList": [
        "ABC"],

Comment: Actually my json is confidential and I made this json for question. In actual json there is no extra comma

Comment: I have corrected given json now

Comment: @R.Henderson ,please check if the updated de-serializer works.

Comment: @samabcde I was away, sure I will implement de-serializer solution on monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason for error

To begin, the reason for the error is that, after you first call `reader.beginObject();`, the JSON reader will go to second line **"$id"**, which is a `NAME` type for [`JSONToken`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/stream/JsonToken.html).
And `gson.fromJson(reader, Student.class);` is expecting the next JSON value is of `BEGIN_OBJECT` type, hence the error occur.

### Solution

Since only a small part from the JSON is required, and the path is not trivial, we can not create a POJO to retrieve data by direct mapping.  As @user10375692 suggests, we can implement `JsonDeserializer` interface for more flexible mapping. In the `deserialize` method, we can use `JSONObject` API to retrieve data from specific path. Following is an example.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class JsonToPojo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = getJson();

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        JsonDeserializer<Example> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Example>() {

            @Override
            public Example deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {
                Example example = new Example();
                JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
                example.setProject(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("properties").getAsJsonObject("project")
                        .getAsJsonArray("projectList").get(0).getAsString());

                JsonObject subElementProperties = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("properties").getAsJsonObject("students")
                        .getAsJsonObject("subelements").getAsJsonObject("properties");
                JsonArray idExamples = subElementProperties.getAsJsonObject("id").getAsJsonArray("examples");
                JsonArray depExamples = subElementProperties.getAsJsonObject("dep").getAsJsonArray("examples");
                List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
                for (int i = 0; i < idExamples.size(); i++) {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setId(idExamples.get(i).getAsString());
                    student.setDep(depExamples.get(i).getAsString());
                    students.add(student);
                }
                example.setStudents(students);
                return example;
            }
        };
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Example.class, deserializer);

        Gson customGson = gsonBuilder.create();
        Example customObject = customGson.fromJson(json, Example.class);
        System.out.println(customObject.getStudents() + ", " + customObject.getProject());
    }

    private static String getJson() {
        return "{                                                  "
                + "  \"$id\": \"students.json\",                   "
                + "  \"type\": \"object\",                         "
                + "  \"properties\": {                             "
                + "    \"project\": {                              "
                + "      \"$id\": \"project\",                     "
                + "      \"projectList\": [                        "
                + "        \"ABC\"                                 "
                + "      ]                                         "
                + "    },                                          "
                + "    \"students\": {                             "
                + "      \"$id\": \"subproject\",                  "
                + "      \"type\": \"array\",                      "
                + "      \"subelements\": {                        "
                + "        \"properties\": {                       "
                + "          \"id\": {                             "
                + "            \"$id\": \"id\",                    "
                + "            \"examples\": [                     "
                + "              \"Y\"                             "
                + "            ]                                   "
                + "          },                                    "
                + "          \"dep\": {                            "
                + "            \"$id\": \"dep\",                   "
                + "            \"examples\": [                     "
                + "              \"X\"                             "
                + "            ]                                   "
                + "          }                                     "
                + "        },                                      "
                + "        \"required\": [                         "
                + "          \"id\",                               "
                + "          \"dep\"                               "
                + "        ]                                       "
                + "      }                                         "
                + "    }                                           "
                + "  },                                            "
                + "  \"required\": [                               "
                + "    \"project\"                                 "
                + "  ]                                             "
                + "}                                               ";
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right about the reason of error. Can I change my java class such that below line automatically map json data to java object:    Student st = gson.fromJson(reader, Student.class);

Comment: I removed this line reader.beginObject();.. Now I am getting no error but data is not mapped to POJO, java object contains empty fields

Comment: Can you post `Student` class also?

Comment: updated classes in question.. Now these are classes which I have made so far

Comment: Is it possible to replace the `Element` class in my solution to your `Student` class since both class have same property?

Comment: yes. Actually what I want is  another class A will provide json and java pojo class name and this json parsing class responsibility is to map provided json into provided POJO

Comment: The annotation you are using (JsonProperty,...) are from jackson library where the json mapping is using gson, please try to use JSONPropertyName and JSONPropertyIgnore instead.

Comment: There is no annotation with name jsonPropertyNmae, I have used @SerializedName from gson but still no luck

Comment: I am unable to implement this. It is giving me error for getDesirialer method. error is: This method must return a result of type JsonDeserializer<Example>